# Loop an If Statement for each row in Sql table

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement

I am trying to make an If statement in PHP loop for each row in an Sql table. I think I'm almost there but there is a syntax error that I cant quite figure out. Heres what i've got so far:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "favourites");

                // check connection
                if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                    die("Connect failed: ".$mysqli->connect_error);
                }

                $query = "SELECT * FROM defaultTiles";
                $result = $mysqli->query($query);

                while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

                echo "<?php if ($tile_name === '$row[name]'){
                    $tile_colour = '$row[colour]';
                    $img_url = '$row[img_url]';
                    $link_url = '$row[link_url]';
                } ?>";
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
     echo "<?php if ($tile_name === '$row[name]'){
                    $tile_colour = '$row[colour]';
                    $img_url = '$row[img_url]';
                    $link_url = '$row[link_url]';
     } ?>";
}
```

with

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
     if ($tile_name === $row['name']){
          $tile_colour = $row['colour'];
          $img_url = $row['img_url'];
          $link_url = $row['link_url'];
     } 
}
```

as, when you put an `echo` in front of the `if` statement, it just prints the statement inside the `echo`.

Comment: Don't forget to de-quote the column values `$row['name']`.

Comment: Thanks alot! Worked perfectly!